# Decimal sorting with radix sort algorithm with python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, floating-point, radix-sort

There are mostly float type numbers in my list and I am getting an error while sorting with radix sort, can you help?

```
 def countingSortForRadix(inputArray, placeValue):
 
     countArray = [0] * 10
     inputSize = len(inputArray)
 
 
     for i in range(inputSize):
         placeElement = (inputArray[i] // placeValue) % 10
         countArray[placeElement] += 1
 
     for i in range(1, 10):
         countArray[i] += countArray[i - 1]
 
     outputArray = [0] * inputSize
     i = inputSize - 1
     while i >= 0:
         currentEl = inputArray[i]
         placeElement = (inputArray[i] // placeValue) % 10
         countArray[placeElement] -= 1
         newPosition = countArray[placeElement]
         outputArray[newPosition] = currentEl
         i -= 1
     return outputArray
 
 def radixSort(inputArray):
     maxEl = max(inputArray)
     D = 1
     while maxEl > 0:
         maxEl /= 10
         D += 1
     placeVal = 1
     outputArray = inputArray
     while D > 0:
         outputArray = countingSortForRadix(outputArray, placeVal)
         placeVal *= 10
         D -= 1
     return outputArray  
data=(2.0,67.5,34,12.4,54)  
print(data)  
print(radixSort(data))
```

## I get an error

list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Answer (score 0):

Radix sort works for integer values. Those integer values can then be used to access the `countArray`.

However, when using float values the array can not be accessed since it requires integer values. So you will keep getting errors at lines numbered 9, 19 and 20.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641059/18511682) gives a more detailed answer regarding the use of floating values in radix sort

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641059/18511682